# How do you wrap a forwardRef component with a HOC?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How do you go about wrapping a forwardRef component?

For example, in my Cell Editor:

```
import React, {useEffect, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useRef} from "react";

export default forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const inputRef = useRef();
    const { someProp } = props;
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
        return {
            getValue: () => {
                return inputRef.current.value;
            }
        };
    });
    return <input type="text" ref={inputRef} someProp={someProp}/>;
})
```

If I wanted to expose a variable (someProp) inside to a HOC, how would I go about doing that?

```
function someProps(WrappedComponent, someProp) {
    return (props) => <WrappedComponent {...props} someProp={someProp}/>
}

someProps(CellEditor, {propName: propValue});
```

Whenever I try to wrap a forwardedRef component, it looks like the ref isn't being recognized correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're returning a wrapped component,  then you have to also forward its reference by using `forwardRef()` and setting the `ref` prop.  Taking your example above:

```
function someProps(WrappedComponent, someProp) {
  return forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <WrappedComponent {...props} ref={ref} someProp={someProp} />
  ));
}
```

Comment: When I try using forwardRef on a component, like Robin's example above, I get an error "function components cannot be given refs". What's the secret sauce to making this work? Newbie here.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose below HOC:

```js
function withErrorBoundary (Component) {
  return (props) => <ErrorBoundary><Component {...props} /></ErrorBoundary>
}
```

**This is NOT usable with `React.forwardRef`**:

```js
const FooWithErrorBoundary = withErrorBoundary(React.forwardRef(Foo))

function Foo(props, ref) {
  // `ref` is `undefined` here (instead of `someRef`)!!!
}

function SomeComponent {
  const someRef = useRef()
  // ...
  return <Foo {...someProps} ref={someRef} />
}
```

---

##### But if we change the HOC implementation to this:

```js
function withErrorBoundary (Component) {
  return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <ErrorBoundary><Component {...props} ref={ref} /></ErrorBoundary>)
}
```

then it works with **both**:

```js
withErrorBoundary(React.forwardRef(Foo)) // function Foo (props, ref) {...}
```

and:

```js
withErrorBoundary(Bar) // function Bar (props) {...}
```